# Getting opid and killOp using mongodb native client

Tags: mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I need to kill specific mongodb operations.

But mongo commands (like `aggregate` or `mapReduce`) whether they're called from the native node client or shell do not return their opids; so I can't match the values in `db.currentOp()` with the specific query that I want to kill.

I tried matching my queries with the `query` property of `db.currentOp().inprog`, but it's far from reliable and in many cases the value of this property will be `"$msg" : "query not recording (too large)"` hence it cannot be matched.

How can I get/assign an ID to my async mongodb queries in order to use this ID to find and kill the query from a (different) connection?

Comment: Can you explain more what specific operations you are trying to kill and why? Can you show us a confusing `db.currentOp()` output that you'd like to be able to reliably parse to determine which ops need to be killed?

Comment: I start a query by: `db.aggregate({...}, (err, result) => {...}` this statement does not retur an opid nor I know of way to identify the opid that is associated with this query in `db.currentOp()`. I just want to be able to kill this query.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using mongodb 2.6? With 2.6 you can set the query timeout via $maxTimeMS

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/maxTimeMS/

Comment: Yes I am aware of it, but I am interested in being able to cancel queries earlier than their `$maxTimeMS` and including mapReduce queries.